# Why can't add PFObject to PFRelation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I would like to add a `PFObject` to a `PFUser`'s `PFRelation`, but unfortunately it doesn't want to work. I'm getting this error:

```
[Error]: wrong type of relation.  Expecting: _User, but received: itemClass
```

Please somebody give me some guidance, because the `PFRelation` class reference states that the `PFRelation`'s `addObject:` method uses a `PFObject` so it must work. Is it possible that I can't add a `PFObject` to a `PFRelation` which belongs to the `_User` class? Thanks!

Here's my implementation:

```
- (void)addItem:(PFObject *)newItem {

    PFRelation *itemRelation = [[PFUser currentUser] relationForKey:@"items"];
    [itemRelation addObject:newItem];

    [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (succeeded){

            NSLog(@"ITEM SAVED");

        } else {

            NSLog(@"Error %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);

        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Is newItem a PFUser?

Comment: @danh newItem is a PFObject.

Comment: But the column is setup as a relation to _User.  Hence the error.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: @danh No, you are totally right. I wanna put PFObjects to a PFRelation in the _User class. I'm confused, because the documentation says the PRRelation addObject: method uses PFObject. Another thing is the PFUser class is a PFObject subclass, so why the PFObject isn't good?

Comment: I think we need to distinguish between how the SDK is written to compile in iOS and how types are handled on the backend.  The operand to a relation only makes sense as specific row in the database.  See the choices when you create a relationship column.  The object you assign needs to match the setup there.

Comment: @danh You're amazing. I created a new relation column, because the first one was created for PFUser and it's perfect. Please write an answer that I can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the column is declared as a relation to `_User`, only a `PFUser` will suffice as an operand to add to the relation.  While `PFUser` is a subclass of `PFObject` in the iOS sdk, the only thing that makes sense to place in a relation is a concrete instance of the relation type.